# How to exclude csv columns in spark?

Tags: apache-spark

`Rdd` consists of entire `csv` records and not able to find ways to exclude particular `colums` from it.

Am tried `drop()`.

For example `CSV File` consists of three `columns no,name and age`.

Now I need to exclude 2 columns no and name

```
Val excluColumns='no,name'    
rdd.drop(excluColumns)
```

Makes Issue in code.

Am new to this `spark` and anyone guide me to do this.

EDIT-1

```
val cols="no,name"
val excluColumns= Seq(cols)
df.drop(excluColumns:_*)
  .show()
```

It leads conversion issue.

Comment: you have rdd or dataframe?

Comment: am having rdd in which having entire records

Comment: can you share how you created the rdd? rdds don't have column names

Comment: My rdd to be like this .rdd=spark.read("CSV File")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**RDDs don't have column names** so *you will have to read it as dataframe and use drop* as (assuming that you have header in the file)

the file should be as

```
no,name,age
1,bill,23
2,charles,24
3,gates,45
```

You read it to dataframe as

```
val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", true).load("File.csv")
```

which should give you

```
+---+-------+---+
|no |name   |age|
+---+-------+---+
|1  |bill   |23 |
|2  |charles|24 |
|3  |gates  |45 |
+---+-------+---+
```

Then you can *create sequence of columns to be dropped* and use it as below

```
val excluColumns= "no,name".split(",")
df.drop(excluColumns:_*)
  .show()
```

This should give you *age column* only

```
+---+
|age|
+---+
| 23|
| 24|
| 45|
+---+
```

Comment: Like i have specified the column names in string "val" in my question.How i pass those string Seq() method.it makes issue

Comment: i have added my EDIT-1 in question. Also, my column names comes in string only not in seperation.

Answer (score 1):

```
  StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                sw.WriteLine("\"Id No\",\"Customer Name\",\"Customer Mobile No\",\"Customer BusinessZone\"");
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Security_User.csv");
                Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
                foreach (var user in _securityUserService.GetAllCustomer())
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(string.Format("\"{0}\",\"{1}\",\"{2}\",\"{3}\"",
                                               user.Id,
                                               user.FullName,
                                               user.Phone,
                                               user.BusinessZones.Name));
                }

                Response.Write(sw.ToString());

                Response.End();
            }
```

Comment: Is this possible in spark ?